# MongoDB pre save set field based on lookup logic

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

People register for an event. There are two collections in the database. One for new registrations coming in and one for the registrations of previous years. Both contain an email field as unique identifier.

I would like to know if its possible to check if a newly registered person has registered before in previous years. If so add a field, for example: `returningCustomer: true`. Otherwise add `returningCustomer: false`

I am using Mongoose and have a `User` model for new registrations. I don't have a model (yet) for previously registered users. Would that be neccesary? If it is possible to check if a person has registered before and a field can be added before saving, it might be handy to save the user to the returning customers collection immediatly as well.

I know it is possible to access the current document and collection using a pre save hook, but how about doing a lookup in another collection, write a bit of logic and add a field to the current document pre save?

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (doc, next) {
    const exists = otherCollection.find({ email: doc.email });
    exists ? doc.returningCustomer = true : doc.returningCustomer = false;
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a model for the collection you want to lookup.

Then you can query the other collection before saving the current collection.

```
CurrentModel.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const doc = await OtherModel.find({ field: this.field });
    doc.length ? this.returningCustomer = false : this.returningCustomer = true;
    next();
});
```